# Differences in how a PHP array is built

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to get an array to output in a key and value format. When I use the second style shown below it works fine, but when I use the first style I don't get the same results. I think something is different in how the keys are used but I'm not entirely sure.

So, is there any difference between building an array like this:

```
$featured = get_post_meta($profileID, 'profile_featured', true);
if ($featured == '1'){$my_fake_pages["featured"] = "Featured";};

$celebs = get_post_meta($profileID, 'profile_celebs', true);
if ($celebs== '1'){$my_fake_pages["coversandcelebrities"] = "Covers &amp; Celebrities";};

$fashion = get_post_meta($profileID, 'profile_fashion', true);
if ($fashion == '1'){$my_fake_pages["fashion"] = "Fashion";};

$beauty = get_post_meta($profileID, 'profile_beauty', true);
if ($beauty == '1'){$my_fake_pages["beauty"] = "Beauty";};

$advertising = get_post_meta($profileID, 'profile_advertising', true);
if ($advertising == '1'){$my_fake_pages["advertising"] = "Advertising";};

$bio = get_post_meta($profileID, 'profile_bio', true);
if ($bio == '1'){$my_fake_pages["bio"] = "Bio";};
```

and writing one like this:

```
$my_fake_pages = array(
    'featured' => 'Featured',
    'coversandcelebrities' => 'Covers &amp; Celebrities',
    'fashion' => 'Fashion',
    'beauty' => 'Beauty',
    'advertising' => 'Advertising',
    'bio' => 'Bio'
);
```

Thanks in advance.

** To be clear, I know one is conditional and the other isn't. What I'm wanting to know is if the output style of the first example is equivalent to that of the second, where the key is the index of the array rather than a number being the index, and the value is still the value.

Comment: Well obviously the difference is that your first code uses conditions...

Comment: What does `get_post_meta()` do?

Comment: As long as `get_post_meta` returns 1 each time, these should produce exactly the same array.

Comment: In order to get a number as an array key, you would have to add the items like `$my_fake_pages[] = "Featured"`, in which case PHP would automatically assign a numeric index. (Or you could explicitly use a number as an array key: `$my_fake_pages[0] = "Featured"`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same. To prove it, I've simplified your code and compared the two generated arrays

```
<?php

$a["featured"] = "Featured";
$a["coversandcelebrities"] = "Covers &amp; Celebrities";
$a["fashion"] = "Fashion";
$a["beauty"] = "Beauty";
$a["advertising"] = "Advertising";
$a["bio"] = "Bio";

$b = array(
    'featured' => 'Featured',
    'coversandcelebrities' => 'Covers &amp; Celebrities',
    'fashion' => 'Fashion',
    'beauty' => 'Beauty',
    'advertising' => 'Advertising',
    'bio' => 'Bio'
);


$same =  !array_diff($a, $b) && !array_diff($b, $a);
var_dump($a);
var_dump($b);    
echo "<br>Same = $same";
```

This outputs:

```
array(6) { ["featured"]=> string(8) "Featured" ["coversandcelebrities"]=> string(24) "Covers & Celebrities" ["fashion"]=> string(7) "Fashion" ["beauty"]=> string(6) "Beauty" ["advertising"]=> string(11) "Advertising" ["bio"]=> string(3) "Bio" } 
array(6) { ["featured"]=> string(8) "Featured" ["coversandcelebrities"]=> string(24) "Covers & Celebrities" ["fashion"]=> string(7) "Fashion" ["beauty"]=> string(6) "Beauty" ["advertising"]=> string(11) "Advertising" ["bio"]=> string(3) "Bio" }
Same = 1
```

Comment: ok thanks. i'll investigate the rest of my code to see what is causing a different end result to be produced further down the line.

Answer (score 0):

The `if()` version only adds to the array if the conditions are met. the second one adds everything, unconditionally. that has nothing to do with the keys.

It's the difference between going to the grocery store with a shopping list and only getting what's on the list, and going to the store and buying 1 of everything.

Comment: No, I know the first uses conditions, but I'm asking if the array would essentially output the same, where the key is the index and the value is, well, the value.

Comment: yes, they're equivalent. doing `$foo = array('bar' => 'baz')` v.s. `$foo['bar'] = 'baz'` are entirely the same thing and produce the exact same array.

Comment: @CoreyRS what's your thought process on how they would be different?

Comment: @Dagon the results i'm getting from actually using the 2 different styles differ. The second works fine but the first doesn't, and I can't figure out why, which is why I came here to ask if there was any difference.

Comment: probably should of lead with the specific issue then. how does the first not work?

Comment: probably the ifs are failing and evaluating to false. so `var_dump($featured)` and see what you're getting back.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question right, you want to know if building an array like this:

```
$my_fake_pages["featured"] = "Featured";
$my_fake_pages["coversandcelebrities"] = "Covers &amp; Celebrities";
$my_fake_pages["fashion"] = "Fashion";
$my_fake_pages["beauty"] = "Beauty";
$my_fake_pages["advertising"] = "Advertising";
$my_fake_pages["bio"] = "Bio";
```

is any different than building it like this:

```
$my_fake_pages = array(
    'featured' => 'Featured',
    'coversandcelebrities' => 'Covers &amp; Celebrities',
    'fashion' => 'Fashion',
    'beauty' => 'Beauty',
    'advertising' => 'Advertising',
    'bio' => 'Bio'
);
```

The answer is no. Both generate an **associative** array (instead of a numbered array) like this:

```
array(6) {
  ["featured"]=>
  string(8) "Featured"
  ["coversandcelebrities"]=>
  string(24) "Covers &amp; Celebrities"
  ["fashion"]=>
  string(7) "Fashion"
  ["beauty"]=>
  string(6) "Beauty"
  ["advertising"]=>
  string(11) "Advertising"
  ["bio"]=>
  string(3) "Bio"
}
```

And also [since PHP 5.4.x](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) you can have a "short syntax" array generation like this (notice the `[]`):

```
$my_fake_pages = [
    'featured' => 'Featured',
    'coversandcelebrities' => 'Covers &amp; Celebrities',
    'fashion' => 'Fashion',
    'beauty' => 'Beauty',
    'advertising' => 'Advertising',
    'bio' => 'Bio'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

> ** To be clear, I know one is conditional and the other isn't. What I'm wanting to know is if the output style of the first example is equivalent to that of the second, where the key is the index of the array rather than a number being the index, and the value is still the value.

Yes, if all conditions evaluate as true, then the array format is exactly the same. Both will be associative arrays with the same key